# path split string with and without subirs

Tags: string, bash, variables, split, sh

how can split this string when if is after / different?

I have such paths :

```
/HDD1/Movies/Excursion.2016/
/HDD1/Movies/Excursion.2016/name1
/HDD1/Movies/Excursion.2016/name2
/HDD1/Movies/Excursion.2016/name3
```

my script :

```
d=/HDD1/Movies/Excursion.2016/
dname=${d#/*/}
dname=${dname%/*}
echo $dname
```

output : Movies/Excursion.2016

```
d=/HDD1/Movies/Excursion.2016/name1
dname=${d#/*/}
dname=${dname%/*}
echo $dname
```

output : Movies/Excursion.2016

I always want everything /Movies/

Example :

```
d=/HDD1/Movies/Excursion.2016/
output : Excursion.2016

d=/HDD1/Movies/Excursion.2016/name1
output : Excursion.2016/name1

d=/HDD1/Movies/Excursion.2016/name2
output : Excursion.2016/name2
```

Comment: Add one more `%`: `dname=${dname%%/*}`

Comment: so dname=${dname%%/*} its output : Movies , the dir Movies can also be different

Answer (score 0):

Try this (warning, bash-specific syntax used):

```
main_dir=/HDD1
complete_path="$main_dir/Movies/Excursion.2016/name2"
if
  [[ "$complete_path" =~ $main_dir/[^/]+/(.+)$ ]]
then
  echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
else
  echo "Path not valid" >&2
fi
```

Comment: In your script, the directory is hard-coded, so how could it be different?  Please describe your intended usage a bit more.

Comment: i can not set main_dir main_dir=/HDD1/Movies, only HDD1 is cant set to main_dir. The dir Movies muss Changeable

Comment: I modified my proposed solution so that one level of directory after /HDD1 is "floating" (ignored).  If you want more information on the bash syntax used (conditional [[ ]] with pattern matching), please comment.